# Bot to my HTML page

Tags: node.js, bots, botframework

I want to use bot created in node.js to work with my html page which I can test.When I open my HTML page, it will have a button which will point to the bot, and then I can use it to further. How can we integrate the node.js part to HTML?  The final output should be like land on my HTML page-select the bot and chat with the bot.
For bots, I have used Microsoft bot framework. I am not getting even is this feasible or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using the WebChat channel iframe embed code to insert the WebChat control into your HTML web page.

You will find the embed code in the channel configuration page for WebChat on the [Bot Developer Portal](https://dev.botframework.com) after you have registered your bot.

[image]

Comment: Yes this worked for me ,I am not proceeding with the configurations part .Thanks for the help

Comment: Hi @Nils W I did embed the code but I am not able to make the chat work. For now I have html file with the iframe code and the node.js script which I want to use on my machine. Can you advice me how to atleast start the communication with Bot?